# Remove pure white from images in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I have an image in Photoshop representing a mountain heightmap.
I'd like to darken a bit the pure white areas, but with the levels tool I'm not able to reach this.
[image: Heightmap example]

This is my current situation:

[image: Wrong]

But, what I want is **this**:

[image: Right]

Could you please suggest a way to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Output levels slider right below...

[image]
Obviously, I've over-cooked that a long way, but essentially that will preserve your gradation, just compressed between more limited extents.

You can do similar in Curves, which would also let you change the levels at intermediate points to emphasise different zones...

[image]

Comment: Oh nice! Is this the equivalent of gradient map?
Because if I do the same in the gradient map, the histogram changes, but with this method it remains the same, despite it's darkening the white areas.

Comment: A Histogram always "adds up to 1, wherever 1 is", it's kind of a sliding scale which isn't dependant on overall brightness, so yes, this will keep the histogram, ir the value differences as percentages of 'the brightest bit'. Adding another method which will let you tweak in more detail...

Answer (score 1):

This is imilar to Tetsujin's answer, but uses an actual curve in a curves adjustment. This has the benefit of being able to target only the brightest areas, without affecting the rest of the image.

[image]